# Print output to console while redirect the output to a file in linux

Tags: python, linux

I am using python in linux and tried to use command line to print out the output log while redirecting the output and error to a txt.file. However, after I searched and tried the methods such as

`python [program] 2>&1 | tee output.log`

But it just redirected the output the the output.log and the print content disappeared. I wonder how I could print the output to console while save/redirect them to output.log ? It would be useful if we hope to tune the parameter while having notice on the output loss and parameter.

Answer (score 2):

the method you found is correct. Here is an example, you can try it yourself.

```
''' a.py '''
print('hello world')


$ python a.py 2>&1 | tee out.log
 hello world
```

So I think your `program` may did not output correctly

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `screen` like this: `screen -L` and then run the python script in this `screen` which would give the output to the console and also would save it the file: `screenlog.0`. You could leave the screen by using `Ctrl+A+D` while the script is running and check the script output by reattaching to the screen by `screen -r`. Also, in the screen, you won't be able to scroll past the current screen view.

Comment: screenlog.0 would be saved automatically ? to where ?

Comment: It will be saved to the directory you do screen -L.